# Linux kernel 4.8.4 custom compilation linux-tools packages not built

Tags: 16.04, kernel, compiling

I have compiled a custom Linux kernel 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 using "Ubuntu way" (patches from mainline PPA e

```
skipabi=true skipmodule=true fakeroot debian/rules binary-indep     
skipabi=true skipmodule=true fakeroot debian/rules binary-perarch 
skipabi=true skipmodule=true fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=parallel=$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) skipabi=true skipmodule=true do_tools=true no_dumpfile=1 fakeroot debian/rules binary-haswell
```

but only linux-tools-common package is built.
I have compiled version 4.8.1 and all linux-tools (common and architecture dependent) packages are built.

Comment: Some Ubuntu thoughts on custom kernels, and support: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile Not sure if there is a consensus on AU re: custom kernels.

Comment: also: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5576/do-custom-kernels-constitute-off-topicness